# Кто сталкивался/пользовался компонентами для работы с базой postgres с PHP?

Tags: php, html, javascript

В общем, есть база постгрес. Сначал все было хорошо. Данные были простые, и толком там не было никакой аналитики/бизнес-логики. Но прогресс не стоит на месте. Есть ли какие компоненты/библиотеки на js для вывода и обработки данных на PHP?

Comment: компоненты\библиотеки на js для вывода и обработки данных на пхп? - а как вы себе это представляете?

Comment: наткнулся на http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/ это оно?

Comment: Ну, предположим, я тяну данные из базы за сутки. И этот компонет объединяет значения по часам и выводит красивую табличку. Да, я знаю, что это можно сделать средствами постгри или своим кодом на пхп\js, но я хочу автоматизации.

Comment: Агрегирование данных, группировку делать надо только на уровне СУБД, в крайнем случае на php (либо другой серверный язык). Вы просто представьте - вы тянете данный за сутки, а их там 1000 шт., и вы будете на JS потом все это разгребать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://datatables.net/download/download